# Should I buy a printer or an iPad pro for reading articles?

Tags: phd, research-process, reading

I assume everybody on this site needs to read articles frequently, which is why I consider this silly question relevant. Due to covid and home-office, I've lost consistent access to a printer, so I contemplate buying one for printing articles, book chapters, etc. Decent laser printers can be bought from €150 where I live. However, large tablets, especially the iPad pro with a 12.9-inch screen, are becoming affordable. Used ones can be bought for €400. I'm not considering e-paper readers, because I do not like the slow page turnaround. Also, smaller tablets are out of the question.

Can anyone comment on using a large tablet vs. printing the articles? What is your experience and what device do you use for your reading needs?

Comment: The main use of my scanner/printer combo is being able to email signed documents. What you prefer for reading is a personal preference and doesn't make a good question for this site.

Comment: I agree that this may be largely determined by personal preference. But I also recall some studies about improved comprehension scores when comparing a text on paper versus on a screen. So that might be part of an answer here.

Comment: I largely use my ipad now (also I can sign stuff directly as a PDF instead of needing to print it and scan it) but it's gonna be personal preference. Make sure you get a pencil if you get the iPad.

Comment: Also low end printers are worthless for printing a lot of papers where the figures are tiny because they get smooshed into illegibility

Comment: I've given up on paper several years ago. Reading electronic versions of papers allows me to highlight and annotate the papers I read. When I review papers, I can also send these annotated copies to the authors.